# How to put multi lines in one Label and define its starting position using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am planning to put one line text with many words into one `Label`, and have the text started from TOP-LEFT in the `Label` area.

Hier I tried with this code:

```
Label_1 = Label(root, textvariable = Labelvar, justify=LEFT, wraplength = 300, anchor=NW)
Label_1.pack(side=TOP)
```

The question is: Although I defined `anchor=NW` , `justify=LEFT` and `side=TOP` , the text is still positioned to Top-Middel.

I also tried some other options for `anchor` , `justify` and `side` , but still cant get the result.

So, how can I get the text started from TOP-LEFT?

Hope you understand my english and my problem.

Thank you all.

Comment: I tested your code and I got the result you expect.

Comment: @Billal BEGUERADJ How could it be. I am confused. Are you using Python2 or 3?

Comment: Actually, running only `anchor = NW` is enough to get the result you expect. This is valid for both versions of Python. I could take a screenshot of my code (I reproduced yours) and post it as answer and remove it after you see it (just in case you do not believe :D )

Comment: @Billal BEGUERADJ I believe you. But how could it be? I am using Python 2 and it is working good. Is it possible if I somehow configued Python wrong?

Comment: No, no, it has nothing to do with Python configuration. Besides, it is Tkinter which is responsible of the result. Can you see the screenshot below? I got the same result in Python 2 and Python 3

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ I have seen it. Thank you.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Now I am really confused. Same code on different computer get different results......

Comment: That is really very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The label will only take as much room as it needs to contain the text, when the root window is resized the label itself will position itself top center even if the text inside it is `justified=LEFT`

To position the label to the left side of the root window use `anchor=W` when `pack`ing it.

```
Label_1.pack(side=TOP, anchor=W)
```

Comment: The OP is trying to position the text of the label to TOP-LEFT

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ yes, but the position of the text in the label is kind of irrelevant if the label is floating in the root window, in that case the position of the label in the root is what matters.

Comment: I can not get it. I tested with a long paragraph but I had no problem. May be I am not understanding the OP's question. Anyway +1 since apparently your contribution is helpful

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ try it again with `root.geometry("800x600")` or similar, you will find that the label positioning itself top center is what the OP was witnessing.  also using `expand=BOTH` to stretch the label out so that the positioning is only relevent to the text inside the widget would work too.

Comment: @Billal BEGUERADJ I didnt know to define anchor= W in the pack definition. Thank you both.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ I tried. But it shows the vote +1 from a beginner cannt be taken. I will do this after I get enough reputation again. But my thankful heart is real.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Thanks for the hint! I have done it.